# Why does binding work on the second level but not on the first level?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS Service defined as follows:

```
function testService(testProvider) {
  var ref = this;
  ref.firstLevel = {};
  ref.secondLevel = {};

  initialize();

  function initialize() {
    testProvider.getData().then(function(result) {
      ref.firstLevel = result;
      ref.secondLevel.testData = result;
    });
  }
}
```

The `testProvider` is a simple wrapper around $http.get that fetches data from a JSON. The controller copies over these properties:

```
function testController(testService) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.firstLevel = testService.firstLevel;
  vm.secondLevel = testService.secondLevel;
}
```

When I create bindings in my template, the second level works, the first level doesn't.

```
<!-- Doesn't work -->
<p>{{vm.firstLevel.testProperty1}}</p>  
<p>{{vm.firstLevel.testProperty2}}</p>

<!-- Does work -->
<p>{{vm.secondLevel.testData.testProperty1}}</p>  
<p>{{vm.secondLevel.testData.testProperty2}}</p>
```

See this Plunker for a working example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/pLInqcaJNhhbQWbvTUEE

Why doesn't the first level example work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you overwrite an object in Javascript, you actually lose the reference to the actual object.

```
testProvider.getData().then(function(result) {
    ref.firstLevel = result;
    ref.secondLevel.testData = result;
});
```

Here `ref.firstLevel = result` overwrites the reference to the object that was initialized to {}. Any data bindings that you had on that object would be lost after this line.

Whereas, by doing `ref.secondLevel.testData = result`, you are not rewriting the object, rather you are only modifying the object by adding an extra key `testData`. Thus the reference is still preserved and so are the AngularJS bindings.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15006802/832780) for more clarity.

Comment: That was my initial theory, but I *thought* I had ruled this out with a test. But I have more faith in your (and my) theory than in the quick test I hacked together :)

Comment: Timing is important here: first the object gets initalized in the service, *then* the controller copies the references to the object, *then* the Promise resolves, replacing the object alltogether. In my (incorrect) test, I replaced the object in the initialize phase of the Service, which is **before** the controller gets its reference, so all seemed to work fine.

Comment: Indeed it is! I kinda guessed that you would be doing something like this when you said about your incorrect test. 

I was thinking that what if we needed to rewrite the object keeping its reference and learned angular.copy has a version which allows us to do it: `angular.copy(source, [destination]);`. Never knew that it could take a second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the `angular.copy` reference, that's a good one to keep in mind! I'm not sure what the performance implications are if you go and deep-copy objects around like that, but let's leave that for another question :)